# Is my method for JPA querying is correct?

Tags: java, jpa

I am using JPA in my web application and when I do not want the DB to return all of the object I do something like:

```
    Query query = super.entityManager.createQuery("select b.id, b.buyName from Buy b where b.id in (:list)");
    query.setParameter("list", buyIds);

    List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
    List<Buy> retval = new ArrayList<Buy>();

    for (Object[] item : result) {
        Buy buy = new Buy();
        buy.setId((Long)item[0]);
        buy.setBuyName((String)item[1]);
        retval.add(buy);
    }

    return retval;
```

That is , querying the fields I want and then manually creating a list of the desired object and populating it.
Is this a good practice? It feels like there is a better way of doing this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to directly return a new object from the query, with just the information that you need. For instance, your query would look like this:

```
select new BuyDTO(b.id, b.buyName) from Buy b where b.id in (:list)
```

And the data transfer object would include only the needed fields:

```
public class BuyDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String buyName;

    public BuyVO(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.buyName = name;
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

When the query is run, it will return a `List<BuyDTO>`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [criteria query](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/jpa_overview_criteria.html) and [named query](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28221/ent30qry001.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you should create a separate **light-weight** POJO (with only the required fields) and then map the result to that POJO.

Comment: isnt that what I am doing but without creating a new POJO?

Comment: You can have multiple mappings for the same class - but then annotation configuration will not work

Comment: @Noam - yes, you are doing something 'similar', but not same. You are explicitly building your POJO (ignoring the fields not required to be populated) rather than have JPA do it for you.

Comment: @Saket - If I understand correctly your method will save me the trouble of creating the "for" loop for the object population? how does JPA does it for me on an unmapped POJO?

Answer (score 0):

If using EclipseLink, you can also set a FetchGroup on the query to define what fields you want back.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup